# shortcut in the windows starting menu - Matlab executable

Tags: windows, matlab, matlab-guide

I create an executable based on a gui with several functions and files, and if I open the executable in the installation folder or using the desktop shortcut everything works fine. If I open through the starting menu, the executable doesn't incorporate the images and doesn’t run. What I can do to prevent this issue? Is it possible to prevent the shortcut in the windows starting menu?

Comment: Your question is out of topic... I think you should modify the "Start in" text of the shortcut (the shortcut in the start menu). In Windows 10 you can find the "Shortcut file" by right clicking the icon (icon in the start menu), select "More" and select "Open File Location". Right click the Shortcut file, and select "Properties". Modify the "Start in" to be the same location as the "Start in" in the desktop shortcut (the shortcut that works).

Comment: I know how to find in a manual way and the right place, my question is how to deal with this issue automatically with matlab. I already tried the function ctfroot instead of pwd in my code, but this installs my files in a temporary place.

Comment: OK, now I think understand the question. You are trying to change the working directory within a deployed application. Am I right? Are you using `deploytool`? Please try to revise your question to be more clear.

Comment: You forgot to give a feedback to my answer. Have you tried it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92949-how-can-i-find-the-directory-containing-my-compiled-application):

You can use the following function to get the folder of the executed `exe` file:

```
function currentDir = getcurrentdir()
if isdeployed % Stand-alone mode.
    [status, result] = system('path');
    currentDir = char(regexpi(result, 'Path=(.*?);', 'tokens', 'once'));
else % MATLAB mode.
    currentDir = pwd;
end
```

Call the function and use `cd` in the GUI opening function:

```
currentDir = getcurrentdir();
cd(currentDir);
```

---

I created a `guide` testing application, and used `deploytool` for compiling and packaging for external deployment.

For testing, I added a text label to the GUI (Tag name: `text2`).

In the GUI opening function I added the following code:

```
% --- Executes just before GuideApp is made visible.
function GuideApp_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;

handles.text2.String = 'Starting...';
pause(1);
currentDir = getcurrentdir();

%Set the label's text to display currentDir.
handles.text2.String = currentDir;

%Change directory to the directory of the exe file.
cd(currentDir);

%Create a file in the directory (just for testing):
f = fopen('currentDir.txt', 'w');fprintf(f, '%s\r\n', currentDir);fclose(f);

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

The above solution is working correctly:
The text of label displays the path of the exe file.
`currentDir.txt` file is created in the path of the exe file.

Comment: Solve my problem. Thanks.